# Jquery: Using countdownTimer getting Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am unable to understand whats wrong in the below code. BTW am using jquery countdownTimer

The library which I have used as follows

http://harshen.github.io/jquery-countdownTimer/#display

```
$(function(){
  $("#counter").countdowntimer({
           hours : 3‚ // Here it is showing the error Unexpected token ILLEGAL
           minutes : 10‚
           size : "lg"
  });
});
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: can you share the entire js ad html in a js fiddle, the js you posted seems to be valid, so it should be in some other part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the white space and re-added it manually and your code now works

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/7jmnvwu1/2/)

[Broken Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/1acmw7n5/)

```
$("#counter").countdowntimer({
    hours : 3,
    minutes : 10,
    size : "lg"
  });
```

There must have been a funky character hidden in there somewhere. I've seen this before when copy / pasting from JSFiddle

Comment: thanks man....now i learned one new point, never copy/paste the code from other sources